What is the exact nuance of 気が付いたように in this sentence?
ホッとして、伊織も肩の力を抜いた.. 気が付いたように眼鏡を掛けなおす。
The character wasn't wearing glasses at the. After getting scared by a friend suddenly barging in, her narration says this.
気が付いたように means "to realize here" why is here associate with glasses

"気が付いたように means "to realize here"" - how did you come to this conclusion? If you were provided a full translation for the line, what was it? What is your own understanding of the full line? I assume 伊織 is the character, or is it somehow the friend? "why is here associate with glasses" - what kind of association do you have in mind? Clearly 掛けなおす is the verb here, and 気が付いたように is an adverbial modifier for it.

I understand that, that-s why I don't understand why "気が付いたように " is used in the context of wearing glasses

Is it not clear why wearing glasses would help with the act of 気が付く?
